# Amazon Alexa smart home skill directive for changing thermostat mode

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am building a smart home skill on amazon alexa. I am trying to figure out a way so that the user can change the mode of thermostat, i.e an user can give it command to set the mode from 'auto' to 'custom'.I cannot figure out which directive to use for that. Or can I create additional commands? I am kind of new to the platform, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you looking for? How to pass the command user telling to Alexa? Or Alexa to connect with thermostat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of October 2017 the Smart Home Skill API includes support for thermostat mode. See the details here:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/build-smart-home-skills-for-hvac-devices.html#setpoints-temperatures-and-thermostat-mode

The end-customer experience has not been launched publicly but will be so when the new Echo devices announced three weeks ago actually ship (end of October).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This info is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify my [smart home SDK](http://github.com/thehappydinoa/alexa-smart-home-skill) to work for this purpose, you would need to make automatic and manual a channel or input depending on how you want to speak. Hope this helps.